# How to send a screenshot with Skype?

Tags: windows-xp, skype

Is it possible to take a screen shot on **Windows XP** and then send that with Skype?

I'm running **Skype version, 6.0.0.126**, and I am not referring to video screen shots either.

Comment: What Operating system?

Comment: @Martin Canaval  MS windows XP SP3

Answer (score 4):

Most user friendly way to take screen shot will be using [GreenShot](http://www.getgreenshot.org) (Open Source).

> Greenshot is a light-weight screenshot software tool for Windows with
>   the following key features:
>
> - Quickly create screenshots of a **selected region**, window or fullscreen; you can even capture complete (scrolling) web pages from
>     Internet Explorer.
> - Easily annotate, highlight or obfuscate parts of the screenshot.
> - **Export the screenshot** in various ways: save to file, send to printer, **copy to clipboard**, attach to e-mail.

Comment: is this Greenshot an independant screenshot tool thatI have to isntall esp. on my computer? Is there any imbeded solution in skype or maybe plug in enables easy screenshot in skype?

Comment: Yes, GreenShot is a Third-Party application which you need to install, it is really handy. It offers you ability to edit, annonate the screen-shot or automatically save it. Otherwise you can follow Martins answer if you don't want to rely on 3rd party tool.

Comment: still i would try to confirm with you Lamb, is it other imbedded screenshot within XP3, so far i heard only Ctrl+prnscrn, Alt+Prnscrn... anything like shift+prnscrn, such imbedded ones?

Comment: @frog Actually, the different shortcuts (you can change these, btw) have different functionality in Greenshot: Print allows you to select a rectangle to shoot (I think that is what you're asking for in a comment above?), Ctrl+Print does a fullscreen shot, Alt+Print does a Window shot. In case you need to send screenshots via Skype, there's a recent post in Greenshot's blog about [how to send screenshots to Skype](http://getgreenshot.org/2013/02/17/how-to-send-an-image-to-skype-using-command-line-arguments/).

Comment: @Lamb in fact I am trying to find some default shortcut of screenshot in Windows OS, becoz to install another software isn't allowed in office computer. I was trying to ask except for the ctrl+print, alt+print, is there other functions for screenshot provided by Win XP? You know sometimes i don't want to shot the whole window, maybe just one button, or just part of the window, some instant messager have such tailored option,where you can adjust the border of the shot at your will.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the OS.

In Windows use the Snipping Tool (I usually just tap the Windows key and type "snip".  The search results will show the tool.  Just click it.

In Mac use can use the hotkey combination CMD+SHIFT+3 to take a snapshot of the full screen.  CMD+SHIFT+4 will let you select a region.  Your screenshots will be saved to the desktop.

In either case, once you have the screenshot, just drag it into Skype to send it to the other party.

Comment: Hi, I didn't find this 'snip' tool, am using MS XP3, could explain more?

Answer (score 1):

On any Windows you can always Hit the <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> (Print Screen) key (the one to the right of the <kbd>F12</kbd> key on a standard keyboard). This will capture the entire screen and put the image it in the `copy paste` buffer in memory. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> will do the same but only for the active window.

Then, open `MS Paint` (or any other image editor) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, this will paste the image captured. Make any modifications you need and save the file. You can even paste this image directly on other applications like MS Word.

Comment: Canaval, somehow i have to often copy paste my screen in skype conversations, while the other chatware like msn has a screenshot which you can tailor your screen image, i couldnt' find it in skype. With PrtScr you can only copy paste either whole screen or the active windows, there seems to be no other solution like more tailored or detailed, right?

Comment: No as far as I'm aware, but you can try with a third party alternative that makes it easier. But I'm not familiar with any.

Comment: Canaval, so to confirm with you, the trick with PrnScrn is only with Alt or Ctrl right? no third option ?I.e Alt+prnscn, Ctrl+prnscn